# I don't want to install gems to ./vendor anymore

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, bundler

I uninstalled the bundler gem and reinstalled it, cleaned out all my gems, removed the vendor/ directory and ran another bundle command. All my gems still went into vendor even though I didn't specify `--path vendor` on the second time around. Is there another `--path` option to set it to default? Where do Rails apps put gems they install to begin with?

Answer (score 0):

You've just discovered one of the reasons for [rvm](https://rvm.io/). rvm will create gemsets that are stored in your user path that you can then version, update or clean if you no longer need them.

This is all done outside of the application path so you can re-use the same gem version across applications, or create new gemsets that are specific to an application. Take a walk through their documentation, once you start using it you'll wonder how you got along without it before.

Comment: Thanks. I'm actually using RVM on the system right now, but it's a multi-user system. I'm currently acting as root, and I'm not sure how I can run `bundle` when that just puts the gems in the app itself, not on the system. As an example, I just learned an hour ago that I've been using the `mysql2` gem for weeks now without ever having installed the gem on the system...

Comment: Even on a multi-user install, you should be able to setup a gemset. Did you `rvm use 1.9.3@app --create --default`? Specifically, the `--default` argument. That's all I've ever done and both gem and bundler installs conveniently show-up in my gemset.